# Two hyperlinks to the same hypertarget. Possible?

Tags: hyperref

I have a need to make multiple links to a single target in my latex generated pdf.  Acrobat supports this, but I don't know how to do it in latex. The target always just goes back to one one the links only, and the other links don't go to the target. Here is the relevant code with a screenshot.

```
\par Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{lamb}}.\par 

\par Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{snow}}.\par 

\par Wherever Mary went the lamb was \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s2}}{}{\hyperlink{t1}{sure }}to go.
```

[image]

Note, only the links "snow" and "sure" are active, while the link "lamb" does nothing. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: show a small but  complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue and possible solutions (but your nesting of \hypertarget and \hyperlink looks curious; anchor and link are two different things).

Comment: note you have two targets both with the name t1, that's  like having  two elements with the same id in html, and can't work.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code is `\hyperlink{s1}{...}`.

This does not work out because in your code the directive `\hypertarget{s1}{...}` does not occur anywhere:

The command `\hyperlink{s1}{...}` denotes the name of a target which is not defined/which does not exist/where in the .pdf-file no named destination=no target=no anchor=no "named navigation-point" is associated to.

---

The macro `\hypertarget` is used to create a named destination=a target=an anchor. Such a thing basically is just a "named navigation-point" which can be referenced by its name.
That "named navigation-point" is placed on the baseline of the box which TeX is about to construct while encountering/processing the `\hypertarget`-command.
If you provide text in `\hypertarget`'s second argument, the "named navigation-point" is also the reference-point of the first thing (box/glue/kern/whatsoever) created from that text.
But you can leave `\hypertarget`'s second argument empty and thus not provide any text at all.
All you need to do is ensuring that there is no break-point between the "named navigation-point" and the box next to it, whose top-left corner you wish to have in the top-left-corner of the  pdf-viewer's display-window when navigating to that named destination=target=anchor="named navigation-point".

The macro `\hyperlink` is used to create a hyperlink in the pdf-file so that clicking the link leads to scrolling the "named navigation-point" denoted as target to the top-left-corner of the pdf-viewer's display-window.

Let's look at an example based on the snippets provided by you:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\par Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{lamb}}.\par

\newpage 

% Here the \hypertarget t1 is created once more instead of creating \hypertarget s1.
\par Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{snow}}.\par 

\newpage

\par Wherever Mary went the lamb was \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s2}}{}{\hyperlink{t1}{sure }}to go.

\end{document}
```

XeTeX creates a file whose format is an extended variant of the good old .dvi-format invented by Donald E. Knuth and then calls another program (xdvipdfmx) for converting that to pdf. This usually happens under the hood and you don't notice.

pdfTeX creates .pdf-files directly. Therefore, **unlike XeTeX,  pdfTeX has builtin-support for tracing whether a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" has been defined more than once and for tracing whether the "named navigation-point" denoted by a `\hyperlink` does not exist. In such cases with pdfTeX-based engines warnings are written to .log-file and console.**

**Like Knuth's TeX XeTeX does not have builtin-support for tracing such things.** It just creates an output-file in extended dvi-format and then calls the program for converting to .pdf. `\specials` are written to the file in extended .dvi-format which contain directives for creating hyperlinks and hypertargets which the program for converting to pdf does handle. But the program for converting to pdf, either, does not have builtin-support for tracing missing named destinations.

Therefore:

- If you compile the above example with a XeTeX-based TeX-engine you won't see warning-messages because unlike pdfTeX-based TeX-engines XeTeX-engines don't have builtin support for tracing missing or duplicate named destinations=targets=anchors="named navigation-points".
- If you compile the above example with a pdfTeX-based TeX-engine/with pdflatex you get the following warnings on the console and into the .log-file:

  ```
  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{t1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
  ```

  ```
  pdfTeX warning (dest): name {s1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
  ```
- If you compile the example with xelatex, using the `-no-pdf`-option, then instead of a .pdf-file as output-file you get a file in extended dvi-format, having the extension .xdv . If you run the converting-program `xdvipdfmx` on that .xdv-file, the converting-program delivers the warning  `xdvipdfmx:warning: Object @t1 already defined.` This corresponds to pdflatex's warning about ' destination with the same identifier '.

*(You didn't say what platform/editor/IDE you use.

If using the online-platform overleaf you may need to click "view raw logs" in order to see all messages produced by the LaTeX-compiler in use.)*

**If you have problems with `\hypertarget`s and `\hyperlink`s it is often a good idea to compile using a pdfTeX-based TeX-engine just to see the warning-messages the pdfTeX-based engine provides. Because these often give a clue whether hyperlinks and hypertargets do match.**

The warnings provided by the pdfTeX-engine tell us that the problem is:

- Attempts at placing into the .pdf-file a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" of name `t1` take place more than once. If this were allowed, the assignment of names to "navigation points" placed into the output-file would no longer be unambiguous/bijective.
- A destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" of name `s1` is not defined/is not placed into the .pdf-file at all. But attempts take place at creating hyperlinks to a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" of that name.

Try something like the following, where for each name of a named destination=of a target=of an anchor=of a "named navigation-point" occurring in the argument of an instance of the command `\hyperlink` a corresponding named destination=a corresponding target=a corresponding anchor=a corresponding "named navigation-point" is actually placed into the .pdf-file via `\hypertarget`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\par Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{lamb}}.\par 

\newpage

% Instead of creating \hypertarget t1 once more the\hypertarget s1 is created.
\par Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s1}{}}{snow}}.\par 

\newpage

\par Wherever Mary went the lamb was \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s2}}{}{\hyperlink{t1}{sure }}to go.

\end{document}
```

No matter if xelatex or pdflatex is used, navigating/clicking links in the resulting .pdf-file should not cause problems as for each hyperklink created via `\hyperlink` a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" created via `\hypertarget` exists.

But the example is just for showing the difference when the mistake of providing a `\hyperlink` where the corresponding named destination=target=anchor="named navigation-point" doesn't exist is rectified.

**If a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point" is placed into the .pdf-file via `\hypertarget`, then you can, via `\hyperlink` of course create more than one hyperlink so that clicking each of the resulting hyperlinks "navigates"/scrolls to the  named destination=target=anchor="named navigation-point" in question.**

I already said that the command `\hypertarget` basically just triggers creating within the .pdf-file a named destination=a target=an anchor=a "named navigation-point". If you wish, you can provide some text in the second argument which will lead to the reference-point of the first thing (box/glue/kern/whatsoever) created from that text and the "named navigation-point" placed into the .pdf-file being the same.

In my humble opinion the text-argument of `\hypertarget` is an invitation to provide confusion.

Like Ulrike Fischer I strongly recommend avoiding confusion by not nesting `\hypertarget`s inside `\hyperlink`s and vice versa.

Instead use `\hypertarget` for just placing a "named navigation point" without any text and ensure that there is no break-point between that "named navigation point" and the box/text whose top-left-corner you want to see in the top-left-corner of the pdf-viewer's displaying-window after clicking a hyperlink which denotes that "named navigation point".

In the end I might probably do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
            %colorlinks=true,
            %linkcolor=blue,
            %filecolor=magenta,
            %urlcolor=cyan,
            %citecolor=green,
            %pdfpagemode=FullScreen
           } 
% ... 
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\RaisedHypertarget{omo}{%
  % Create a named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" without text.
  % In relation to the baseline of the box which TeX is about to construct 
  % while encountering the command `\RaisedHypertarget`
  % - move named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" up in an amount of #1,
  %   defaults to \baselineskip   
  % - move named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" to the left in an
  %   amount of #3, defaults to 2mm   
  % #1 - Amount of space to move the named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" up
  % #2 - Name of named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point"
  % #3 - Amount of space to move the named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" to the left. 
  %      You may need this in case the named destination/target/anchor/"named navigation-point" is at the
  %      left of a hyperlink with borders for ensuring that the "named navigation-point" is not inside the 
  %      link's borders but at the left thereof as well as otherwise things might be scrolled so that you do not see the left
  %      border of that link when navigating to the named destination.
  %
  % For vertical placement use \Hy@raisedlink and probably within a local scope redefine
  %  \HyperRaiseLinkHook and/or \HyperRaiseLinkDefault,
  % see section "8 Help macros for links" of "Hypertext marks in LaTeX", the user manual of hyperref.
  % URL: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref.pdf#section.8
  \begingroup
   \IfNoValueF{#1}{\def\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{#1}}%
   \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#2}{}}}%
                   {\Hy@raisedlink{\kern\dimexpr-#3\relax\hypertarget{#2}{}\kern\dimexpr#3\relax}}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}%
\pagecolor{white}%
\noindent Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{lamb}.
\par
\noindent Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{snow}.
\par
\noindent Wherever Mary went the lamb was \hyperlink{t1}{sure} to go.
\par\newpage
\noindent Mary had a little \RaisedHypertarget{t1}[1pt]\hyperlink{s1}{lamb}.
\par\newpage
\noindent Whose fleece was white as \RaisedHypertarget{s1}[1pt]\hyperlink{s2}{snow}.
\par\newpage
\noindent Wherever Mary went the lamb was \RaisedHypertarget{s2}[1pt]\hyperlink{t1}{sure} to go.
\par\newpage
\noindent Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{lamb}.
\par
\noindent Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{snow}.
\par
\noindent Wherever Mary went the lamb was \hyperlink{t1}{sure} to go.
\end{document}
```

You can compile this example both with xelatex and with pdflatex.
pdflatex does not deliver warning-messages related to missing/duplicate named destinations=targets=anchors="named navigation-points".

As you can see there are several links leading to the named destinations=targets=anchors="named navigation-points" `s1`, `s2` and `t1`.

I recommend viewing the resulting pdf with a very large zoom factor so that besides the vertical scrolling you can also see how things get scrolled horizontally when clicking a hyperlink.

Comment: I wouldn't nest hyperlink and hypertarget but move the target command before the link. While it works I think setting the anchor and creating links are independant tasks and it would be less confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I am using xelatex. Just to clarify: if I  delete the first line ('mary had a little lamb'), I am left with 2 sentences which cross reference to each other.  Assuming the word "sure" is the target, the question then can be restated:  how do I code a further link somewhere in the document that can ALSO cross reference to "sure". It's not necessary for  "sure" to cross reference back also to that extra link.

Comment: % standard headings - compiler is xelatex
% ...
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan, citecolor=green, pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
% ...
\begin{document}\pagecolor{white}\noindent

\par Mary had a little \hyperlink{s1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{lamb}}.\par 

\par Whose fleece was white as \hyperlink{s2}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{snow}}.\par 

\par Wherever Mary went the lamb was \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s2}}{}{\hyperlink{t1}{sure }}to go.\par 

\end{document}

Comment: @dedalus I just edited my answer and added a few explanations. Hth. Happy LaTeXing.

Comment: @dedalus The first line is `\hyperlink{s1}{...}`.  This does not work out because in your code the directive `\hypertarget{s1}{...}` does not occur anywhere. So the hyperlink denotes a target which is not defined/which does not exist/where no "navigation-point" is associated to.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to  Ulrich Diez for throwing light on the issue of multiple hyperlinks  going to a single target.

I've posted my poor solution below, which while not particularly novel, nonetheless was not easy to come by, as googling and looking at the hyperref docs gave me no help at all.

It's very common to find  many to one links in pdf's, but I couldn't find any clear way of doing it in latex.  A typical scenario is a thesis in which several keywords link to a common reference in an index or bibliography. The reference, when scrolled to, can be clicked itself so as to go back to the originating keyword in the text.

But wait, if  there are  multiple keywords linking to the reference, which one does the reference link back to?  As far as I am aware, pdf's (or latex) don't support cycling through a list of hyperlinks (like a browser which implements a back button) .. in fact neither do the major word processors like Word or Google docs.

What (I think) pdf's do is to go back from the target reference to ONE of the links. We can call this the home link. It's  usually the last in the list of links which connect to the target reference. At least a large Acrobat file of a thesis I have containing hundreds of links targeting dozens of references does  it this way.

This image illustrates how a pdf  handles cross linking, and below it is a schematic of my implementation.

[image]

Here is a simple demo file which I compile with xelatex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan, citecolor=green, pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{white}

\par     \hyperlink{s1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t1}{}}{Target link}}. 

\par     \hyperlink{t1}{First link}. 

\par     \hyperlink{t1}{Second link }

\par     \hyperlink{t1}{Third link }

\par     \hyperlink{t1}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{s1}{}}{Home link }}

\par 
\end{document}
```

This is good enough for my purposes, but any further thoughts or improvements are welcome.

Comment: You can go back in most pdf viewers with ctrl+a . Some have also a menu or a button.

Comment: Maybe so, but In my acrobat reader, ctrl +a gives me Select All.   There is an ALT + left/right arrow which navigates back and forth through the history of page views, but  that has nothing to do with link navigation. I havn't discovered any way using acrobat of cycling through common links to a single reference as described in my graphic.

Comment: yes, sorry I meant that key. And yes that is link navigation, it is quite similar to what a browser does. The html *code* doesn't contain link cycles, it is the viewer (the browser) which remembers history, for pdf it is the task of the pdf viewer. It doesn't make much sense to define one of your targets as home target if you don't know how your reader navigate through the document.